# Query related to fancybox in facebook page tab

Tags: facebook, fancybox

I want to use fancybox in a facebook tab based page. In that page there are seperate pages loading in fancybox, but what is happening is I can not give width of that page more than 520px as my fancybox opens inside the facebook page so there is a scrollbars in my facebook page. Is there a way where I can load my fancybox as overlay on full page so there my new pages that are opening in fancybox can have more than 520px width.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, you only have control over the space that Facebook gives to you in your iFrame.  There are certain dialogs you can ask Facebook to display, see if one of them fits your needs.